# Passing array of objects generated dynamically to onclick handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dom-events

I am generating an `onclick` handler dynamically and setting it using the `attr` method.

```
var originReference = "myDynamicString";
var stringArray = [];
stringArray.push("Data1");
stringArray.push("Data2");
var objArray = [];
objArray.push({name: "Category 1", y: 10});
objArray.push({name: "Category 2", y: 20});

onclickReference.attr("onclick", "drawChart('" + originReference + "',[" + stringArray + "],[" + objArray + "]); return false;");
```

With this code, the `objArray` is not being passed properly to the handler event as I am getting the error:

> "SyntaxError: missing ] after element list".

Using just an array of strings (no JSON). The data is passed to the handler just fine.

How can I format my object array in the `onclick` handler?

Comment: I don't think you need to concatenate the vars. you can simply use drawChart(originReference,stringArray,jsonArray);

Comment: P.S. There is no "JSON array" anywhere in this code.  Your `jsonArray` is just an array of objects.  JSON is a *string representation* of data, that resembles JavaScript object/array syntax.  If it's not a string, it's not JSON.

Comment: Thanks, I stand corrected. Changed the verbiage in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `onclick` attributes to bind events.  Use `addEventListener` to add events.

```
onclickReference.click(function(){
    drawChart(originReference, stringArray, jsonArray);
    return false;
});
```

EDIT: According to your comment, you are binding events in a loop.  In that case you need to create a closure to "capture" the values of your variables.

Try this:

```
onclickReference.each(function(){
    // Define your variables inside this new scope
    var originReference = "myDynamicString";
    var stringArray = [];
    var objArray = [];

    this.click(function(){
        drawChart(originReference, stringArray, jsonArray);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: My `onclickReference` is populated like this: `onclickReference = $(this).find("a");`. Therefore, `addEventListener` throws a **not a function** error. If I reference `$(this).find("a")[0];` my data doesn't seem to be there

Comment: Didn't realize `onclickReference` was a jQuery object.  In that case, it's just `onclickReference.click(function(){...});`.

Comment: This doesn't work because I am iterating through a set of "a" elements where the value of originReference and objArray changes for each event listener. In this case, the value of all the variables passed to the function in my click event will be whatever the final value was. I need it to change based on the value during the iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You should use JSON.stringify to convert your javascript object to json string.

```
onclickReference.attr("onclick", "drawChart('" + originReference + "'," + JSON.stringify(stringArray) + "," + JSON.stringify(jsonArray) + "); return false;");
```

But as @Rocket Hazmat said, use `onclick` attribute is a bad way to do event binding.